# Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sec^{-1}x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sec^{-1}x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Here is my method:

Let $y=\sec^{-1}x$ then $\sec(y) = x$

Find the Derivative of $\sec(y) = x$:

$\sec(y)\tan(y)\cdot y\ \frac{dy}{dx}=1$

Isolate $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sec(y)\tan(y)}$

I don't know if I am doing this correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done a little mistake.
$$y=\sec^{-1}x\\\implies\sec y=x\\\implies\sec y\tan y\frac {dy}{dx}=1\\\implies\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1{\sec y\tan y}=\frac 1{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

**EDIT:**
Now, you assumed $y=\sec^{-1} x$ and thus,$$\sec y=x\tag 1$$

You know that, $$\tan^2 y+1=\sec^2 y\tag 2$$

It is merely a geeneral trigonometric identity, it has no relation with calculus.

Note that,$$\tan^2 y+1=\frac {\sin^2 y}{\cos^2 y}+1=\frac {\sin^2 y+\cos^2 y}{\cos^2 y}=\frac 1{\cos^2 y}=\sec^2 y$$

Now, $$\sec y=x\\\implies \sec^2 y=x^2. $$

Replace this in $(2)$, then you have, $$\tan^2 y+1=x^2\\\implies \tan^2 y=x^2-1\\\implies \tan y=\sqrt{x^2-1}\tag 3$$

Now, multiplying $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have,$$\sec y\tan y=x\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

Replace this term in the expression $\frac {dy}{dx}$

*this completes your proof.*